# Azure DevOps Multi-Tenant Release Stage

Tags: iis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a single codebase that is deployed to ~30 website instances on 3 Virtual Machines.  Once code is tested and signed off on I have manual trigger with Pre-deployment approvals.

I was wondering if there is a way to have a Stage (Production) with multiple websites associated to them vs. having to create a separate stage for each customer such as prod_client1, prod_client2, etc.

I googled this topic and was unable to find anything on it.  I can appreciate the granularity of deployments but the redundancy and commonality of the stages would be frustrating.  Guidance or best practices would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Does each website have it's own build and release pipeline? Granularity like this helps with the flexibility when deploying single sites rather than always pushing them all.

Answer (score 1):

> if there is a way to have a Stage (Production) with multiple websites
>   associated to them

For this issue,you could add multiple deploy tasks to a stage's agent job.Specific deploy tasks are selected according to your needs.You can also try adding a PowerShell task to the agent job, deploying a code base to multiple websites on a stage via a powershell script.

However, multi-stage deployment is recommended for the situation where you want to deploy to multiple websites.The benefits of doing this is mentioned in Dejulia489's comment.